# Set Notation (Axiom of Replacement)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

This question is related to the one I asked yesterday [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394150/set-notation-axiom-of-infinity) in that it's related to another one of the [Zermelo-Fraenkel Axioms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Zermelo-FraenkelAxioms.html). After looking over the notation used to describe the axiom, that is:

$$ \forall \space x \space \forall \space y \space \forall \space z \space [\varphi (x,y,p) \wedge \varphi(x,z,p) \Rightarrow y = z] \Rightarrow \forall \space X \space \exists \space Y \space \forall \space y \space [y \in Y \equiv (\exists \space x \in X) \varphi(x, y, p) ]  $$

I believe I understand most of it, but I'm unsure of why we need to involve the variable z, so I thought I'd just write how I'm interpreting this and have someone correct me where it starts to get fuzzy.

> Current Interpretation: For all the elements of the three sets $X, Y, Z,$ if the property $\varphi$ holds under some parameter $p$ for $x, y $ and $x, z$ conjointly implies that $y$ equals $z$ then for any set X there exists a set Y such that for any element of $Y$ there exists an element of X such that property $\varphi$ holds under both the element of $Y$ and the chosen element of $X$ for that property $p$.

What I'm confused about is the purpose of the extra parameter $p$ and the set $Z$ why couldn't you just say something like this:

$$ \forall \space x \space \forall \space y \space \varphi (x,y) \Rightarrow \forall \space X \space \exists \space Y \space \forall \space y \space [y \in Y \equiv (\exists \space x \in X) \varphi(x, y, p) ]  $$

What am I missing here? Also if someone could clear up my interpretation that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $x=x$ for $\varphi(x,y)$. Then your version of the axiom gives us a universal set $Y$: every $y$ is in $Y$.  So it leads to an inconsistent theory.

The part that says that $\varphi(x,y,p) \land \varphi(x,z,p)$ implies $y=z$ says that the relation $\varphi$ is "function-like." It is a very strong set construction principle, but does not (one hopes) lead to inconsistency.

Comment: Hmm the second part makes sense to me. I can see how if that part held it would be function-like, but I don't quite understand the first-part where you say let $x = x$ . Does this mean you just replace the $Y$ and $y$ with $X$ and $x$? Sorry if its a dumb question, trying to teach myself a few topics over the summer

Comment: I am saying let $\varphi$ be any formula which is always true. Instead of $x=x$ we could even use something that does not "mention" $x$ and $y$ at all, such as "there exists an empty set." Then if you trace through the meaning of your axiom for that choice of $\varphi$, it turns out that it says there is a $Y$ such that every (set) $y$ is an element of $Y$. From this we can deduce the Russell paradox.

Comment: Alright this is starting to make more sense to me, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. The traditional "Axiom of Separation" produced only subsets of already constructed sets. *Replacement* goes beyond that, but cautiously. It says that if we have an already constructed set $X$, and a "function-like" relation $\varphi$, then the "range" of $\varphi$, as $x$ varies over $X$, is a set.